# Как вывести куки в node.js их функции от MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Жизнь в некоторых лицах заставила из тепленького, уютного PHP погрузиться в суровый JavaScript в исполнении Node.js.
При выполнении ниже приведенного кода выдает ошибку "can't set headers after they are sent"
Так понял, что кука не отправляется в виду невозможности изменения внешней переменной res. А как же тогда отправить куку? Или хотябы вывести хоть какую-нибудь переменную из анонимной функции.

Читал что выводят как-то через колбаки, но везде примеры выводят результат в консоль (в этих примерах все понятно), а примера вывода результата в живую нету.

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser("SDFSF"));
})
app.use(express.cookieSession());

var mongo=require('mongodb').MongoClient;

function change_status(req,res) {
    var db=mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/shop", function(err, db) 
     {
        var collect_users = db.collection('users');

        collect_users.find().toArray(function(err,items)
        {           
            if(items[0]['hash']==req.cookies.hash)
            {
                res.cookie('status','active', { maxAge: 1000*60*10 });
            }
            else
            {       
                res.cookie('status','noactive', { maxAge: 1000*60*10 });
            }   
        });
    });
};

app.get("/",function(req,res){
change_status(req,res);
res.send("erewrwerew");
})

app.listen(2012);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все дело в том, что у Вас res.send() выполняется раньше чем устанавливаются куки.

mongo.connect - асинхронная операция, поэтому программа инициализирует соединение с БД и выполняет код дальше. То есть если рассматривать код линейно, то задача фукнции change_status сводиться только к инициализации соединения, после чего фукнция считается выполненной. А это значит, что вслед за ней будет выполнена функция res.send(). Ну а после того как будет установлено соединение с БД, будет неудачная попытка отправить куки. Неудачная потому, что заголовки уже отправлены функцией res.send().

Решается все довольно просто. Мы должны выполнить res.send() после того как будет установлено соединение с БД и установлены куки. Для этого передадим третьим аргументом функцию обратного вызова (callback) в функцию change_status, которая будет вызываться тогда когда нам надо:

```
function change_status(req,res, callback) {
    var db=mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/shop", function(err, db) 
     {
        var collect_users = db.collection('users');

        collect_users.find().toArray(function(err,items)
        {           
            if(items[0]['hash']==req.cookies.hash)
            {
                res.cookie('status','active', { maxAge: 1000*60*10 });
            }
            else
            {       
                res.cookie('status','noactive', { maxAge: 1000*60*10 });
            }   
            callback();
        });
    });
};

app.get("/",function(req,res){
     change_status(req,res, function() {
          res.send("erewrwerew");
     });
})
```

В callback можно передать любые данные, полученные из БД, а из коллбека в res.send... Кстати, find - тоже асинхронная операция. Да и вообще все операции ввода/вывода в node.js - асинхронные. Так что будьте внимательны, и успехов! :)